# Solr API using Java

Tags: java, solr, solrj, solrcloud

I am trying to use solr API to index all documents of xmls and pdfs(xmls and pdfs all in one folder again like there are many folders) using java in a certain folder may be vary in count , I need basic idea and java code for this please

```
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient;
import org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument;

import java.io.IOException;

public class SolrjPopulator {
public static void main(String[] args) 
throws IOException, 
SolrServerException {
SolrClient client = new HttpSolrClient.Builder("http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1").build();
for(int i=0;i<1000;++i) {
  SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
  doc.addField("cat", "book");
  doc.addField("id", "book-" + i);
  doc.addField("name", "The Legend of the Hobbit part " + i);
  client.add(doc);
  if(i%100==0) client.commit();  // periodically flush
}
client.commit(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: you can use apache tika to extract the content of the documents and index it using solr...currently it seems a very vague question...

Comment: check this link for more help https://lucidworks.com/post/indexing-with-solrj/

Comment: My data gets in the format of folders i mean 1 xml and 1 pdf in a single folder and then 2 xmls and 2 pdfs in other folder how can i index these those above folders are at one place